# Converting Unix Timestamp to PHP Date(), Year doesn't work

Tags: unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert a Unix Timestamp to a date using php.

But I can't seem to get the Year to work. What am I doing wrong?

Unix Timestamp: `1409522400000`

```
gmdate("d-m-Y", 1409522400000)
```

PHP date: 27-12-**46635**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unix timestamp is in milisecconds, php uses seconds. Remove the last three zeroes and you get:

```
date('d.m.Y H:i:s', 1409522400); //01.09.2014 00:00:00
```

**Update:**
If you are getting the timestamp from an api, you can divide the timestamp by 1000;

```
$ts = 1409522400000;
date('d.m.Y H:i:s', round($ts / 1000));
```